# Video should be in between the text and the images

Tags: html, css

I have a quick question: on my page that I coded for uni, I have a problem with positions and size. I want my video to fit in between the text and the images without overlapping. Currently it is overlapping on the bottom when my browser window is shrunk. Do you have any idea on how to fix this?
I tried with margins and different percentages of the height of the div that the video is in but I couldn't find a solution... I also tried setting the overall size of my page but that pretty much ruins my page.

You can find the div under ".tutorialvideo" in my css.

```css
/* Allgemeines Styling */

body,
html {
  width: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 2400px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  font-family: Baskerville, Helvetica, serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: .2em;
  color: #A5A58D;
  background-image: url(file:///Users/alinasprenger/Documents/FH%20St.%20Po%CC%88lten/Interaktive%20Medien/Screendesign%20Website%20WS20/Pottery%20Website%20Background%20Blurred-1.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}


/* Große Überschrift "Alina's Pottery" */

.header1 {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 50px 0 20px 0;
  font-size: 41px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


/* Navigationsleiste */

nav {
  background: #B7B7A4;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 30px #00000030;
}

nav a {
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav.categoryContainer ul,
nav.categoryContainer li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

ul {
  background: #B7B7A4;
  height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 42px;
  padding: 0 1em;
  color: #FFF1E6;
}

li a:hover,
.category>li:hover>a {
  background: #AEAE98;
  height: 42px;
  position: relative;
}

.current,
a:hover.current {
  background: #909072;
  color: #FFF1E6;
  position: relative;
  height: 42px;
  cursor: default;
}

.category li:hover ul {
  left: 0;
}


/* Dropdown-Menü */

ul.dropdown {
  float: none;
  background: #FFF1E6;
  color: #B7B7A4;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  left: -9000em;
  z-index: 5;
  padding-right: 0%;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 30px #00000030;
}

ul.dropdown>li {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}

ul.dropdown li a {
  color: #B7B7A4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #B7B7A4;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul.dropdown li a:hover {
  background: #FFE8D6;
}

.categoryContainer>ul>li:hover>.dropdown {
  left: 0;
}

ul.dropdown li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}


/* Überschrift : "Tutorials" */

.header3 {
  font-size: 41px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #A5A58D;
  color: #EDDCD2;
  /*flex-wrap: wrap;*/
  /*position: absolute;*/
  /*top: 80px;*/
  /*margin-top: 80px;*/
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 3;
}


/* Text-Block 1, pottery.html */

.textparagraphen1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 485px;
  height: 445px;
  background-color: #A5A58D;
  color: #EDDCD2;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 15px;
  top: 239px;
  right: 53%;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 23px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 30px #00000030;
}

.text1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #EDDCD2;
}

.quelle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
}


/* Text-Block 2, pottery.html */

.textparagraphen2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 485px;
  height: 445px;
  background-color: #A5A58D;
  color: #EDDCD2;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
  top: 970px;
  left: 53%;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 23px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 30px #00000030;
}


/* Text-Block 3, pottery.html */

.textparagraphen3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 485px;
  height: 445px;
  background-color: #A5A58D;
  color: #EDDCD2;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
  top: 1525px;
  right: 53%;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 23px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 30px #00000030;
}


/* Text-Block 4, tutorials.html */

.textparagraphen4 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 68.4%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #A5A58D;
  color: #EDDCD2;
  /*flex-wrap: wrap;*/
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 90px 15% 0 15%;
  /*top: 255px;*/
  /*position: absolute;*/
  line-height: 23px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 30px #00000030;
}

.text2 {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  top: 80px;
  padding: 0 2em;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.links {
  padding: 0 0 50px 0;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.text3 {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  /*top: 300px;*/
}

section.textparagraphen4 ul,
section.textparagraphen4 li {
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #EDDCD2;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0;
}

section.textparagraphen4 a {
  font-size: 22px;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.25;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

section.textparagraphen4 a:hover {
  height: auto;
}


/* Bilder, pottery.html */

img {
  max-width: 660px;
  max-height: 660px;
}

.abbildung1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 53%;
  top: 239px;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 30px #00000030);
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 30px #00000030);
}

.abbildung2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 53%;
  top: 784px;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 30px #00000030);
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 30px #00000030);
}

.abbildung3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 53%;
  top: 1525px;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 30px #00000030);
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 30px #00000030);
}


/* Bilder, tutorials.html */

.bildabschnitt img {
  max-width: 622px;
  max-height: 622px;
}

.abbildung4 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 53%;
  top: 1640px;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 30px #00000030);
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 30px #00000030);
}

.abbildung5 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 53%;
  top: 1640px;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 30px #00000030);
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 30px #00000030);
}


/* Tutorialvideo aus YouTube */

.tutorialvideo {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

iframe {
  width: 70%;
  height: 756px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Footer-Menü */

.footerContainer {
  top: 2322px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #A5A58D;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #A5A58D;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.footer2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #A5A58D;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-image"></div>
<div class="header1"> Alina's Pottery </div>

<nav class="categoryContainer">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html" title="Home" class="category">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="pottery.html" title="Pottery" class="category">Pottery</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="general.html" title="General" class="subCategory">General</a></li>
        <li><a href="handbuilding.html" title="Hand-Building" class="subCategory">Hand-Building</a></li>
        <li><a href="potterywheel.html" title="Pottery Wheel" class="subCategory">Pottery Wheel</a></li>
        <li><a href="materials.html" title="Materials" class="subCategory">Materials</a></li>
        <li><a href="temperatures.html" title="Temperatures" class="subCategory">Temperatures</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="current"><a href="tutorials.html" title="Tutorials" class="category">Tutorials</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="viewall.html" title="View All" class="subCategory">View All</a></li>
        <li><a href="getstarted.html" title="Get Started" class="subCategory">Get Started</a></li>
        <li><a href="plates.html" title="Plates" class="subCategory">Plates</a></li>
        <li><a href="mugs.html" title="Mugs" class="subCategory">Mugs</a></li>
        <li><a href="bowls.html" title="Bowls" class="subCategory">Bowls</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="shop.html" title="Shop" class="category">Shop</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="products.html" title="Products" class="subCategory">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactform.html" title="Contact Form" class="subCategory">Contact Form</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section class="textparagraphen4">
  <div class="header3">
    Tutorials
  </div>

  <div class="text2">
    <p>
      These videos should give you a kick-start to pottery, explaining the basics,<br> clearing up common mistakes and offering inspiration for your future projects.<br> Pottery is actually super easy to learn - everybody can do it.<br> That’s why I want
      to give you all the tools to start out even as a total beginner.<br>
      <br> Follow these links to get to the different tutorials:<br>
    </p>

    <div class="links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="getstarted.html" title="Get Started" class="linksammlung"> GET STARTED</a></li>
        <li><a href="plates.html" title="Plates" class="linksammlung"> PLATES </a></li>
        <li><a href="mugs.html" title="Mugs" class="linksammlung"> MUGS </a></li>
        <li><a href="bowls.html" title="bowls" class="linksammlung"> BOWLS </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="text3">
      <p>
        And always remember: imperfect ceramics are way better and more personal than perfect ones!
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>

<!-- Folgender Div ist ein eingebettetes Video aus YouTube, welches laut Validator fehlerhaft ist.-->
<div class="tutorialvideo">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JOko1ygjPwk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<section class="bildabschnitt">
  <div class="abbildung4">
    <img src="file:///Users/alinasprenger/Documents/FH%20St.%20Po%CC%88lten/Interaktive%20Medien/Screendesign%20Website%20WS20/PotteryPage-7.jpg" alt="Clay">
  </div>

  <div class="abbildung5">
    <img src="file:///Users/alinasprenger/Documents/FH%20St.%20Po%CC%88lten/Interaktive%20Medien/Screendesign%20Website%20WS20/PotteryPage-8.jpg" alt="Plates">
  </div>

</section>

<div class="footerContainer">
  <a href="aboutme.html" title="About Me" class="footer">About Me</a>
  <a href="socials.html" title="Socials" class="footer"> Socials</a>
  <a href="imprint.html" title="Imprint" class="footer2">Imprint</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to refactor your `html` into something like:

```
 <section class="wrapper">
    <div class="text3">
      <p>
          And always remember: imperfect ceramics are way better and more personal than perfect ones!
      </p>
    </div>
  
    <div class="tutorialvideo">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JOko1ygjPwk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="bildabschnitt">
        <div class="abbildung4">
            <img src="file:///Users/alinasprenger/Documents/FH%20St.%20Po%CC%88lten/Interaktive%20Medien/Screendesign%20Website%20WS20/PotteryPage-7.jpg" alt="Clay">
        </div>

        <div class="abbildung5">
            <img src="file:///Users/alinasprenger/Documents/FH%20St.%20Po%CC%88lten/Interaktive%20Medien/Screendesign%20Website%20WS20/PotteryPage-8.jpg" alt="Plates">
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
</section>
```

then CSS:

```
.text3 {
  flex: 1;
}

/* Bilder, tutorials.html */
.bildabschnitt img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 622px;
  max-height: 622px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

/* Tutorialvideo aus YouTube */
.tutorialvideo{  
  background: transparent;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
  flex: 1;
}

iframe {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 756px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Have a look at this link about responsive `iframe` https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_iframes.asp

and also, https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: Add a relative position to the section (.bildabschnitt) where are the images and delete the top attribute for the images, thats why the overlap with the video.

But I recomend you to stop using or mixing positions with displays. It doesn't seem necesary here.